# Error while fetching value from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, plist

This is the code, i'm trying to save data in a plist if the value (score) is more then the old value (maxscore), but i found an error...

```
func write() { var maxscore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("chiave") as Int?

    if let test = score { // ERROR            
        if maxscore < score {
            maxscore = score
        }
    }
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(score, forKey: "chiave")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

the ERROR for Xcode is

```
"bond value in a conditional binding must be optional type swift"
```

EDIT NEW PROBLEM ! i write the plist at the end of the game and i want to read the plist when the game start, to show the maxScore in the score labelScore... but i've a new error and i'm going crazy to solve it!

```
    func write() {

    var maxScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("chiave") as Int?
        if maxScore < score {
            maxScore = score
    }

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(maxScore, forKey: "chiave")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}

func read() {

    var maxScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("chiave") as Int?

    println(maxScore)  // CONSOLE RETURN -> "Optional(0)"

    labelScore.text = String(maxScore) // ERROR "Could not find an overload for init that accept the supplied argument
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand why this was down voted.... It's a legitimate question.

Comment: Your question says about plist file writing, where as your explanation mentions about NSUserDefaults.

Comment: i really don't understand, i'm new in coding and i've a sample project that save a simple string and it work perfectly, but this way edited whit integer and not string don't work in my project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this:

```
var maxscore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("chiave") as Int?
```

Should be this:

```
var maxscore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("chiave") as? Int
```

Also, where does `score` come from a bit later?  It appears that Swift is complaining because it's not optional.  If this is the case, you can just do this and forget the if statement:

```
if maxscore < score {
    maxscore = score
}
```

Although, that doesn't really make much sense because you don't do anything w/ maxscore after that.  What I think you meant to say is this:

```
if maxscore < score {
    score = maxscore
}
```

I will mention this again, don't cast using 'as Int?' Cast using 'as? Int'. You should not be doing it that way. Change your read to this:

```
if let score  = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("chiave") as? Int {
    labelScore.text = "\(score)" 
}
```

Comment: score is declared in the viewcontroleller. the problem is not solved with your solution... same error in the same place...

Comment: The error is because score isn't an optional, can you show how it's declared?

Comment: Yea, that's your problem.  It's not an optional, so optional binding won't work.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer to show that one as well. Any more errors/questions should be posted as new after this one. Good luck w your project :)